# Prototype to JQuery conversion - stuck with class.create

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, prototypejs

I'm a novice who's trying to convert code from prototype to JQuery. I'm getting through the basics but am stuck with the code below. I've tried using jquery extent but cannot work it out. Here is the code, I'd really appreciate some help.

```
var SaveForm = Class.create();
SaveForm.prototype = {
    formId: null,
    responseText: null,

    initialize: function(formId)
    {
            this.formId = formId;
    }, 
    sendRequest: function(idform)
    {
            var referenceThis = this;
            $(idform).request(
            {
                      onSuccess: function(transport)
                      {
                              referenceThis.responseText = transport.responseText;
                              referenceThis.onSuccess();
                      },
                      onFailure: function(transport)
                      {
                              referenceThis.responseText = transport.responseText;
                              referenceThis.onFailure();
                      }
            });
    },
    onSuccess: function()
    {
    },
    onFailure: function()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Class inheritance is outside the scope of jQuery, I would suggest using one of the many existing pre-built methods for doing this (jQuery does not come with one built-in.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is made for DOM, Event handling, Ajax and Animation. Creating "classes" is not in its scope.

However, you can easily transform it to a simple plain JavaScript constructor function and prototype methods:

```
function SaveForm(formId) {
    this.formId = formId;
    this.responseText = null;
}
SaveForm.prototype.sendRequest = function(idform){
    var _this = this;
    $(idform).request({
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            _this.responseText = transport.responseText;
            _this.onSuccess();
        },
        onFailure: function(transport){
            _this.responseText = transport.responseText;
            _this.onFailure();
        }
    });
};
SaveForm.prototype.onSuccess = function(){};
SaveForm.prototype.onFailure = function(){};
```

However, I'm not sure which of these methods you actually need. jQuery has no `request` method, and to do Ajax requests just use the powerful [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, and the Defereds functionality. Sounds like all you need is

```
 function submitForm(id) {
     var $form = $('#'+id);
     return $.ajax({
         url: $form.attr("target"),
         method: $form.attr("method"),
         data: $form.serialize(),
         dataType: "html"
     });
 }
 // Usage:
 submitForm("myForm")
   .done(function onSuccess(responseText) {…})
   .fail(function onFailure(error) {…});
```

Comment: I found rewriting the code and using $.ajax was the best way to go. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The translation would look like that:
- you don't need to use 'Class.create()'
- you have to use new 'new' when creating a new SaveForm instance
- change 'referenceThis' to _this.

Why do you pass 2 times the formId? only once in the initialize should be enough

```
var SaveForm = function(){
    this.formId;
    this.responseText;
};

SaveForm.prototype.initialize = function(formId){
    this.formId = formId;
}

SaveForm.prototype.sendRequest = function(idform){
    var _this = this;
    $(idform).request({
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            _this.responseText = transport.responseText;
            _this.onSuccess();
        },
        onFailure: function(transport){
            _this.responseText = transport.responseText;
            _this.onFailure();
        }
    });
};

SaveForm.prototype.onSuccess = function(){};
SaveForm.prototype.onFailure = function(){};


var form = new SaveForm(); // 'new' is very important!!
form.initialize('myId');
```