# Prototype to JQuery conversion - stuck with class.create and classname.prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I was trying to convert a whole prototype file contains about 480 lines to jQuery.
We do not use prototype library.

I got something to convert [convert online](http://andykdocs.de/andykdocs/document/Migrating-from-the-Prototype-JavaScript-Framework-to-jQuery/Andyk-Docs-Prototype-To-jQuery-Migration-Tool-Automated-Transformation-Version-1.html)
But it seems it will only work for few. But he has given lots of tips.

My doubt is how to start ?
When i browse in stackoverflow i got so many...
if we are completely changing from prototype to jquery do we need to use the word 'prototype'. ?
example : [prototype to jquery - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802953/prototype-to-jquery-conversion-stuck-with-class-create)

```
var buildAShop = Class.create();
buildAShop.prototype = {
    initialize: function (parameters) {
        var params = parameters.evalJSON(); // passing json object so we can add more variables from jsp if needed.
        this.scheduleSearchAjax = null;      // keep track of the latest scheduleSearch ajax call to ensure only the last one gets displayed.
        this.intrastitialContent = null;     // store the intrastial content from the page so all HTML is in the jsp page.

        // create controller object for all shops and their info
        this.shopObj = {currentShop: params.selectedShopNumber,
                          shopNumbers: params.shopNumbers,
                                            shopNumbersForSelectedSlices: params.shopNumbersForSelectedSlices};

        for (var i = 0; i < params.shopNumbers.length; i++) {
            var thisShopDiv = $(params.shopNumbers[i].toString());
            var thisShopHeader = thisShopDiv.getFirstElementByClassName('shopHeader');

            // observe the shop header for changing shops and highlighting the 'tab'
            Event.observe(thisShopHeader, 'click', this.switchShop.bindAsEventListener(this, params.shopNumbers[i]));
            Event.observe(thisShopHeader, 'mouseover', this.hoverHeader.bindAsEventListener(this, thisShopHeader, 'on'));
            Event.observe(thisShopHeader, 'mouseout', this.hoverHeader.bindAsEventListener(this, thisShopHeader, 'off'));

            // initialize this shopSet
            this.initShopSet(thisShopDiv, params.shopNumbers[i], params.shopNames[i]);
        };
    },

    // initializes a shop set
    initShopSet: function (thisShopDiv, shopId, shopName) {
        this.shopObj[shopId] = {};

        var flt = this.shopObj[shopId];
```

I havn't given the whole code here.

Answer (score 0):

The `Class.create()` method in PrototypeJS allows you to easily build out Javascript objects just like if you were building in normal OOP languages (Java, PHP, etc)

however jQuery core doesn't have a direct correlation for `Class.create()` so you would need to build the Javascript object using native Javascript prototypes.